# How to get initial 200users from AD group membership using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a AD group "xyz" having 1500 members in it. I want to select initial 200 users and send emails to them.

I am not sure how to filter the 200 users from the group using PowerShell code,i have all members list but want to know how can I filter 200 users from it?

please help

Comment: By what criteria do you want to select the _"initial 200 users"_ ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, there is no specific criteria for it, it will be better if we go with sorting user name @Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abort a pipeline after receiving X input objects with `Select-Object -First X`:

```
Get-ADGroupMember xyz |Select-Object -First 200
```

If you want a *random* sample, use `Get-Random -Count`:

```
Get-ADGroupMember xyz |Get-Random -Count 200
```

Beware that Active Directory doesn't guarantee any specific sort order, so you'll have to manually keep track of which users you've already processed (if you want to only process each member once for example)